# Probability of someone not getting chosen

Tags: probability

> During a game of musical chairs, 10 people walk around eight chairs waiting for the music to stop. Find the probability of a person not getting a chair.

I have a hard time understanding probability to be honest. I thought the answer to this would simply by $\frac{2}{10}$ but I feel like I might need to use combinations for this, however I can't figure out how I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unstated assumption is that all the people are equally likely to get a chair.  Then you are correct that the chance a particular person does not get a chair is $\frac 2{10}$.  The chance that some person does not get a chair (which is another way of reading what you wrote) is $1$.